# Converting Uint8Array to BigInt in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, biginteger, data-conversion, uint

I have found 3 methods to convert Uint8Array to BigInt and all of them give different results for some reason. Could you please tell me which one is correct and which one should I use?

1. Using **bigint-conversion** library. We can use `bigintConversion.bufToBigint()` function to get a BigInt. The implementation is as follows:

```js
export function bufToBigint (buf: ArrayBuffer|TypedArray|Buffer): bigint {
  let bits = 8n
  if (ArrayBuffer.isView(buf)) bits = BigInt(buf.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 8)
  else buf = new Uint8Array(buf)

  let ret = 0n
  for (const i of (buf as TypedArray|Buffer).values()) {
    const bi = BigInt(i)
    ret = (ret << bits) + bi
  }
  return ret
}
```

2. Using DataView:

```js
let view = new DataView(arr.buffer, 0);
let result = view.getBigUint64(0, true);
```

3. Using a FOR loop:

```js
let result = BigInt(0);
for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i++) {
  result = result * BigInt(256) + BigInt(arr[i]);
}
```

I'm honestly confused which one is right since all of them give different results but do give results.

Comment: Do you know which [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) you want?

Comment: @Ry- I'm fine with either BE or LE but I'd just like to know why these 3 methods give a different result. I've tried running the for loop from 0 to end instead of reverse but it still was giving me different results.

Comment: There is something wrong with the last example. Why would you multiply by 256?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I found this code snippet on stackoverflow too.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski: Because 256 is 2^8. It’s correct, for little-endian.

Comment: That `DataView` will only work with 64 bits, as the name `getBigUint64` suggests. The last snippet works only with an `Uint8Array`, unlike the first snippet which works with any typed array or buffer - also they use different endianness.

Comment: "*all of them give different results*" - please show how you are calling them, with what input.

Comment: "*I have found 3 methods*" - please link the places where you found them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm fine with either BE or LE but I'd just like to know why these 3 methods give a different result.

One reason for the different results is that they use different endianness.

Let's turn your snippets into a form where we can execute and compare them:

```
let source_array = new Uint8Array([
    0xff, 0xee, 0xdd, 0xcc, 0xbb, 0xaa, 0x99, 0x88, 
    0x77, 0x66, 0x55, 0x44, 0x33, 0x22, 0x11]);
let buffer = source_array.buffer;

function method1(buf) {
  let bits = 8n
  if (ArrayBuffer.isView(buf)) {
    bits = BigInt(buf.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 8)
  } else {
    buf = new Uint8Array(buf)
  }

  let ret = 0n
  for (const i of buf.values()) {
    const bi = BigInt(i)
    ret = (ret << bits) + bi
  }
  return ret
}

function method2(buf) {
  let view = new DataView(buf, 0);
  return view.getBigUint64(0, true);
}

function method3(buf) {
  let arr = new Uint8Array(buf);
  let result = BigInt(0);
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    result = result * BigInt(256) + BigInt(arr[i]);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(method1(buffer).toString(16));
console.log(method2(buffer).toString(16));
console.log(method3(buffer).toString(16));
```

Note that this includes a bug fix for method3: where you wrote `for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i++)`, you clearly meant `i--` at the end.

For "method1" this prints: `ffeeddccbbaa998877665544332211`
Because method1 is a big-endian conversion (first byte of the array is most-significant part of the result) without size limit.

For "method2" this prints: `8899aabbccddeeff`
Because method2 is a little-endian conversion (first byte of the array is least significant part of the result) limited to 64 bits.
If you switch the second `getBigUint64` argument from `true` to `false`, you get big-endian behavior: `ffeeddccbbaa9988`.
To eliminate the size limitation, you'd have to add a loop: using `getBigUint64` you can get 64-bit chunks, which you can assemble using shifts similar to method1 and method3.

For "method3" this prints: `112233445566778899aabbccddeeff`
Because method3 is a little-endian conversion without size limit. If you reverse the `for`-loop's direction, you'll get the same big-endian behavior as method1: `result * 256n` gives the same value as `result << 8n`; the latter is a bit faster.
(Side note: `BigInt(0)` and `BigInt(256)` are needlessly verbose, just write `0n` and `256n` instead. Additional benefit: `123456789123456789n` does what you'd expect, `BigInt(123456789123456789)` does not.)

So which method should you use? That depends on:
(1) Do your incoming arrays assume BE or LE encoding?
(2) Are your BigInts limited to 64 bits or arbitrarily large?
(3) Is this performance-critical code, or are all approaches "fast enough"?

Taking a step back: if you control both parts of the overall process (converting BigInts to Uint8Array, then transmitting/storing them, then converting back to BigInt), consider simply using hexadecimal strings instead: that'll be easier to code, easier to debug, and significantly faster. Something like:

```
function serialize(bigint) {
  return "0x" + bigint.toString(16);
}
function deserialize(serialized_bigint) {
  return BigInt(serialized_bigint);
}
```

Comment: "*Using hexadecimal strings will be significantly faster*" - that's a real shame, isn't it? One would hope that copying the bytes from the internal bigint representation into a buffer (or the other way round) is faster, and more space efficient, than string parsing and serialisation.

Comment: >  Additional benefit: 123456789123456789n does what you'd expect, BigInt(123456789123456789) does not.)

Could you please explain this? I am unable to use 256n because typescript complains: "BigInt literals are not available when targeting lower than ES2020."

Comment: @Bergi: a built-in BigInt <-> ArrayBuffer conversion routine could indeed be more efficient; the chunking/shifting/masking you need when building this in userspace is going to be slower. That said, using hex strings is a fine solution, I think; it's not clear whether having some other facility would be worth it.

Comment: @WorChan: Just try `BigInt(123456789123456789)` at the console and see what happens. The explanation is that `123456789123456789` is a Number literal and as such has limited precision; converting it to BigInt afterwards can't magically restore the lost bits.

Comment: @WorChan You should definitely change your TypeScript options to fix that warning if you want to use bigints.

Comment: @jmrk If all I'm doing is using BigInt(x) where x is a 2 digit number at most, then it should be fine right?

Comment: @WorChan more verbose and less efficient than it could be, but no danger of precision loss for 2-digit numbers. Keep in mind that there is no JS engine in existence that would support `BigInt(1)` but not `1n`; at best the former can be transpiled away slightly more easily, but TypeScript won't do that for you, you'd have to manually use some BigInt polyfill library. Otherwise you might as well configure TS to target ES2020.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store really big integers that isn't bound to any base64 or 128 and also keep negative numbers then this is a solution for you...

```js
function encode(n) {
  let hex, bytes

  // shift all numbers 1 step to the left and xor if less then 0
  n = (n << 1n) ^ (n < 0n ? -1n : 0n) 

  // convert to hex
  hex = n.toString(16)
  // pad if neccesseery
  if (hex.length % 2) hex = '0' + hex

  // convert hex to bytes
  bytes = hex.match(/.{1,2}/g).map(byte => parseInt(byte, 16))

  return bytes
}

function decode(bytes) {
  let hex, n

  // convert bytes back into hex
  hex = bytes.map(e => e.toString(16).padStart(2, 0)).join('')

  // Convert hex to BigInt
  n = BigInt(`0x`+hex)

  // Shift all numbers to right and xor if the first bit was signed
  n = (n >> 1n) ^ (n & 1n ? -1n : 0n) 

  return n
}

const input = document.querySelector('input')
input.oninput = () => {
  console.clear()
  const bytes = encode(BigInt(input.value))
  // TODO: Save or transmit this bytes
  // new Uint8Array(bytes)
  console.log(bytes.join(','))

  const n = decode(bytes)
  console.log(n.toString(10)+'n') // cuz SO can't render bigints...
}
input.oninput()
```

```html
<input type="number" value="-39287498324798237498237498273323423" style="width: 100%">
```